# How to export a subdocument without creating an empty collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a document that has an array of another sub-document. I need to be able to export the sub-document for use elsewhere. I am using `mongoose.model` and this works, however, it creates an empty collection in my database that is just never used. How can I prevent this behavior?

Usage example:

```js
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    
    const ChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        childName: String
    });
    
    const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        parentName: String,
        children: [ChildSchema]
    });
    
    module.exports = {
        Parent: mongoose.model("parent", ParentSchema),
        Child: mongoose.model("child", ChildSchema)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Mongoose model without creating a collection in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685504/how-to-create-a-mongoose-model-without-creating-a-collection-in-mongodb)

Comment: Yep, that does it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `autoCreate` and `autoIndex` options on your Schema:

```js
const ChildSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  autoCreate: false,
  autoIndex: false,
  childName: String
});

const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  parentName: String,
  children: [ChildSchema]
});
```

Comment: This is close, but doesn't quite do it. First, I want the ParentSchema to have collection, so I don't need it on that. Most importantly, I had to add `autoCreate` and `autoIndex` as false on the child.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to add `autoIndex` to the answer. I just updated it. Thanks!